# Back4app, filter query based on null value or undefined value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

In database seems we have two types of non existing values:

(undefined) and (null)

If I do query

```
if paidDateDoesNotExist == true {
 query.whereKeyDoesNotExist("paidDate")
}
```

looks like it returns only undefined but no null records which is seems correct.

If I do query

```
if paidDateDoesNotExist == true {
 query.whereKey("paidDate", equalTo: NSNull())
}
```

it returns the all undefined and null records.

So for some cases I need to clear value from client code. Let's say I have `paidDate` column and I want to clear `paidDate` which was set to some Date already.

in my client code I just simple assign `NSNull()` to `PFObject`

like `pfObject["paidDate"] = NSNull()`

in this cases query `query.whereKeyDoesNotExist("paidDate")` will not work.

So the thing I would like to understand - do I need to assign `pfObject["paidDate"] = (undefined)` value somehow or I just need to use another query which is uses `NSNull()` as filter.

Which is more fun when I use similar query form the admin panel, admin panel returns records which are equal to null only ignoring undefined records. But for client code query:

```
if paidDateDoesNotExist == true {
 query.whereKey("paidDate", equalTo: NSNull())
}
```

returns undefined records as well as null records.

[image]

Comment: I'd user `pfObject["paidDate"] = NSNull()` to clear values and `query.whereKey("paidDate", equalTo: NSNull())` to search for null values.

Comment: yea this is what works for me also